# Azure AD B2C in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to integrate Azure AD B2C in the ASP.net core MVC application. It is showing the login page initially and when clicking on Login after entering username and password, it goes into a loop. When click on stop loading this page icon in the browser, it shows the home page An error occurred while processing your request. (Details Correlation failed).

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmADq.png)

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios,      see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
```

app.UseHsts();
}

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

in the console it showing below log repeatedly.

Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter: Information: IDX10245: Creating claims identity from the validated token: '[PII of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebToken' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.

Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter: Information: IDX21305: OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.ProtocolMessage.Code is null, there is no 'code' in the OpenIdConnect Response to validate.

Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter: Information: IDX21310: OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken is null, there is no 'token' in the OpenIdConnect Response to validate.

Comment: Check if this helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application?tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Please check the link that @Sridevi provided; app.UseAuthentication() comes before app.UseAuthorization().

Answer (score 0):

> The below  ASP .NET Core code is for authentication and authorization using Azure AD B2C. Microsoft Identity services are used for Azure AD B2C, and token acquisition is set up for downstream API calls. Thanks to @Sridevi for providing the link to [Enable](https://github.com/dzimchuk/azure-ad-b2c-asp-net-core/tree/master/TestApp) authentication in your own web app by using Azure AD [B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application?tabs=visual-studio).

**Startup.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using TestApp.Infrastructure;
using TestApp.Proxy;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
            
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
               
                options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();
            });

        

            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"))
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { Configuration["TestService:Scopes"] })
                .AddDistributedTokenCaches();

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); // for other options see https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/token-cache-serialization

            services.AddRazorPages()
                 .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI()
                 .AddMvcOptions(options => options.Filters.Add(typeof(ReauthenticationRequiredFilter)));

            services.AddOptions();
            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));

            services.AddTransient<TestServiceProxy>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```html
@using System.Security.Principal

<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span class="navbar-text text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="EditProfile">Edit Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Created one **Sign up and Sign In** user flow named `B2C_1_SUSI` in B2C tenant like this:

[image]

Register one Azure AD B2C application and add redirect URI in `Web` platform:

[image]

**appSettings.json:**

```json
{

  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com",
    "Domain": "b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "appId",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/user_flow_name",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "user_flow_name",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_PasswordReset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_ProfileEdit",
    // To call an API
    "ClientSecret": "secret",
    "ClientCertificates": [
    ]

  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:44349"
      }
    }
  },
  "TestService": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5001",
    "Scopes": "openid"
  }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]